# connect to encoder via eth0

Tags: networking

I have ubuntu 14.04 and
I am trying to connect to other device(encoder) via eth0.
Encoder has ip address 239.168.168.55.
I set my static ip address via network connections.
In IPv4 settings I put Method manual:

```
Address 239.168.168.67
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Gateway 239.168.168.1
```

I am able to establish connection and paste into console:

```
sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
```

This gave me results as follows:

```
Interface: eth0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-                                                                                                                  monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
239.168.168.55  00:0b:78:00:60:01   TAIFATECH INC.
```

In next step I tried to put 239.168.168.55 into web browser(chromium) but I get:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

I try to ping this address:

```
ping 239.168.168.55
```

but I got:
    connect: Invalid argument

I tried also nslookup but it gave me timeout.
I am looking for any tip/ clue how can I manage this connection.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this data:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 239.168.168.67
gateway 239.168.168.55
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 239.168.168.0
broadcast 239.168.168.255
```

Comment: If I understand You correctly I should edit /etc/netwrork

Comment: Yes. Edit file /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: I edit this file and paste what You wrote but I am not able to start eth0 connection.  Interfaces looks as follows :`#
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 239.168.168.67
gateway 239.168.168.55
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 239.168.168.0
broadcast 239.168.168.255
`After pasting I write in terminal: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` and I got `ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
`

Comment: You must disable nmcli or put data  In IPv4 settings.

Comment: I put it via IPv4 settings. I establish connection but after putting ip address (239.168.168.55 ) in web browser I got: `This webpage is not available

ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT` In IPv4 there is no broadcast field but I think it is calculated from other values

Comment: Try:  'ping 239.168.168.55'